# Makefile {a,b,c} globing equivalent

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

How to do in a Makefile ?

The equivalent of the following bash:

`$ rm -f {a,b,c}_foo/*.csv`

This Makefile

```
$ cat Makefile
clean:
   rm -f {a,b,c}_foo/*.csv
```

Does not work

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Usually you'll have makefile variables that contain the list of files that it creates, and you use that same list for deletion.

Comment: `rm -f $(add-prefix a b c,_foo/*.csv)` Personally I prefer to do as many expansions in _make_ syntax as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use bash, not sh.

Makefile:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

clean:
    rm -f {a,b,c}_foo/*.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

[gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) has a glob-matcher - but only standard glob syntax, not the extended one from bash. In your case this is sufficient nevertheless:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

allfiles := a_foo/x.csv a_foo/x.txt b_foo/b.csv c_foo/c.csv c_foo/read.me

$(foreach thisfile,$(allfiles),$(if $(call glob-match,$(thisfile),[abc]_foo/*.csv),$(info deleting $(thisfile))))
```